# What workout works for me?

Tags: workout

I am a kid 15 years and I want to get stronger physically. I don't want to look big and almighty.

What kind of workout ( bodyweight cuz I cant do gyms) can u suggest? Any diet?

To give perspective of my current strength.
3- Push ups
25- Squats
3- Chin ups ( 0 pull ups)
10- Lunges

I can manage any length and diet so please help me.

Comment: Building muscle mass takes quite a long time and quite a lot of effort. Even if you're actively trying to look "big and almighty" it won't happen for a few years at minimum. Don't cheat yourself, challenge yourself in every workout you do. Also, resistance bands/tubing is fairly cheap, portable, and a great overall option.

Comment: @JustSnilloc *"I **don't** want to look big and almighty."* (Emphasis mine.)

Comment: That’s exactly my point though, this kid isn’t going to get big and bulky even if he/she is trying. Not for a few years at any rate.

Comment: What about strength and endurance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you can do more than 20 reps of an exercise; that exercise is too light and you should find another one. I suggest you replace the squat with bulgarian split squat. You can use a park bench to rest one leg. Since you can do 25 squats I guess you can do ca. 10 of these.

Chin-ups/pull-ups work the back and you should keep doing them.
You should also do australian pullups for your back. These are lighter than pull-ups. For your shoulders to stay healthy it is better to have more horizontal pulling (australian pull ups) than vertical pulling (chin ups/pull ups).
It is very important to have a strong back. In fact your back should be stronger than your chest. When your chest is stronger than your back you get rounded shoulders and start to look like a gorilla. You don't want that.

Push ups is a good exercise. You should keep doing these.

Plank variations are good for strong abs and lower back. You should do these.

Hanging leg raises are also good for the abs.

A big problem with bodyweight exercises is training the hamstring and the glutes. The deadlift is the most important strength exercise there is. There is really no bodyweight alternative for this. Ideally you should get hold of a bar and your own weight in plates. Another alternative that might work is to do sprint training.

Answer (score 2):

I think your best bet is to get googling. Research different types of plans and what the goals of each are and whether they match up with what you want. Personally I am a bodyweight workout aficionado both due to the decreased injury risk and the convenience. Regardless though the keys are to make a plan that is balanced includes all muscle groups and stick to that plan.

Now for some recommendations (Disclaimer I've used some of this and I am compensated by none of these)

Nike training club has a bodyweight only version plan through their app. It will give a week by week plan of exactly what you should do and includes a pretty good variety of workouts and goals.

AthleanX is a fitness program run by a guy named Jeff Cavaliere who is also a physical therapist. He trains lots of professional athletes and is generally considered to know what he is doing. He offers a bodyweight only version of his plans on their website.

Freeletics is a freemium app that works to build a community around training and focuses on their own version of "functional" fitness. I personally have found success with it.

There are some staples of any bodyweight program. Pull ups/pushups/burpees/squats will all help you improve your overall fitness. Find something that includes all of the above and you should be good.

Answer (score -3):

if you want to focus only on your strength, the solution is sure a routine with multi-joint exercise (like bench-press, deadlift, squat, military press, trctions and dips), with a simple 6x6 or 5x5.

Comment: OP is asking for bodyweight exercises (no access to gym), but you suggest typical barbell exercises. Your answer is very condensed even OP seems to be inexperienced. Your "multi-joint exercise" suggestion is good: It replies on "what kind of workout". Perhaps you can explain why or back it up with references. Also notice what parts the existing answer by "ford perfect" is missing to address: "Any diet?".